# org.apache.struts.ServletException :JavaBean is not found

Tags: java, jsp, struts

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserSearchJB {

public UserSearchJB(){
    System.out.println("UserSearchJB");

}

public ArrayList searchRecords(UserDTO udto) throws SQLException{
        UserSearchDAO  usdao = new UserSearchDAO();
        ArrayList list = usdao.searchRecords(udto);
        return list;
    }
}
```

//This is the code for javabean using struts flow.
This is for model to transfer the data one component to another component

Comment: Could you post your UserSearchDAO class and stacktrace? Did you remember about using all necesarry ejb annotations?

Comment: Post the entire exception.

Answer (score -1):

What is the problem in this program i think it is a basic program in which import two spacial package import java.sql.SQLException; and
import java.util.ArrayList;

Comment: pacakges were imported (see his edited question), otherwise code would not even compile.